'htmx:confirm' event firing on every ajax call
I'm attaching a htmx:confirm event listener to the body so as to override the default browser confirm UI with sweetalert2 library as shown in this example. However I'm running into unnecessary prompts every time Htmx makes an ajax call. Below is my Html.
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>htmx test</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>TODOs</h1>
        <div id="content" hx-get="https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1" hx-trigger="load">
            <p>...loading</p>
        </div>
        <br/>
        <button id="btn-change" hx-get="https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/2"  hx-target="#content">Change TODO</button>
        <button id="btn-change-w-confirm" hx-get="https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/3" hx-confirm="Are you sure you want to change todo?" hx-target="#content">Change TODO w/Confirm</button>
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/htmx.org@1.9.12" integrity="sha384-ujb1lZYygJmzgSwoxRggbCHcjc0rB2XoQrxeTUQyRjrOnlCoYta87iKBWq3EsdM2" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@11"></script>
        <script>
            document.body.addEventListener('htmx:confirm', function(e) {
                console.log('htmx:confirm', e.detail);
                e.preventDefault();
                Swal.fire({
                    title: e.detail.question,
                    showCancelButton: true,
                    icon: "warning",
                }).then(function(result) {
                    if(result.isConfirmed) e.detail.issueRequest(true);
                });
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>

The expected behavior is only #btn-change-w-confirm should be displaying the confirm message as it has hx-confirm attribute. However the confirm message is displayed by all ajax calls including when the page loads and the other button without the confirm.

Is it normal for htmx:confirm event to be raised by every Ajax call or is there something I'm missing?
https://jsfiddle.net/qc3nwuez/

I have added a check to verify that only events arising from elements with attribute hx-confirm can show the confirm message.
document.addEventListener("htmx:confirm", function(e) {
    const confirmMessage = e.detail.elt.getAttribute("hx-confirm");
    if(confirmMessage){
        e.preventDefault();
        Swal.fire({
            title: confirmMessage,
            showCancelButton: true,
            icon: "warning",
        }).then(function(result) {
            if(result.isConfirmed) e.detail.issueRequest(true);
        });
    }
});


I think you could also just move the event to a different element instead of the body. May be more in line with HTMX’s “locality of behavior” doctrine. But I agree, this is another one of HTMX’s unintuitive quirks and should be changed. If you wanted to intercept all ajax requests, there are plenty more descriptive events to do it.

@BenderBoy I attached it to the body as I want all prompts to use Sweetalert2 UI. There was an issue opened on Github but was closed unresolved. https://github.com/bigskysoftware/htmx/issues/2029
